# solving for a set number of "accelerating" values between two given values

Tags: linear-algebra, roots, exponential-sum

In this array of five values, the relationship between each value is doubled:

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
```

Now let's say I only have the outer bounds of an array of the same size (the size here will always be **five**). Note that the outer values can both change in my scenario:

```
[1.4, x, y, z, 11]
```

How would I solve for `x,y,z` in such a way that the difference between each value in the array increases in an "accelerating" fashion? By "accelerating," I mean the values are not equidistant from each other, but the values increase in by a consistently calculated amount each time.

I believe this could technically be considered "exponential" growth, but the exponent is not a whole number, as it is in the first array example.

Since I don't even know what this is called, my tags may be totally wrong.

Comment: Just as $16 = 2^4$, you have $11 = x^4$.

Comment: This is confusing.  Do you mean:  "find a value $r$ such that $r^4=11$"?  If so then $x=r, y=r^2,z=r^3$,  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @user296602 - ok, so when I solve for the 4th root of 11, I get `1.8211...` and that seems to work. But does that only work if the first value is 1? I don't see a variable in your suggestion that represents the initial value.

Comment: @lulu - Your first assumption is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first term is $a_0$, your array is $[a_0,a_0\delta,a_0\delta^2,a_0\delta^3,a_0\delta^4]$. You know the first and last terms, so $a_0=1.4$ and $a_0\delta^4=11$. You therefore have $\delta=\sqrt[4]{11/1.4}$

Comment: Awesome thanks. is /delta the common symbol for this type of equation? or was that just an arbitrary choice?

Comment: Purely arbitrary, but based on the fact that it is used to describe a change

Comment: What would the formula be if the numbers in the array were mean to descend to a lower value? So instead of `[1.4, x, y, z, 11]`, something like `[6.7, a, b, c, 1.2]` ?

Comment: The same approach would work. Just reverse the sequence so it's increasing, calculate the terms, then reverse the sequence again